# React, Firebase - The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I've set up a little project with firebase and react. I want to deploy it, but the npm run build fails. It could be possible that firebase produced this error, if there using dynamic import.
My imports look like this or similar:;

## My imports

```js
//React, Bootstrap
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";
import "bootstrap";
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "../../../node_modules/firebase/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "../../../node_modules/firebase/firebase-analytics.js";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
  sendEmailVerification,
} from "../../../node_modules/firebase/firebase-auth.js";
import {
  getDatabase,
  ref,
  set,
} from "../../../node_modules/firebase/firebase-database.js";
```

## My package.json

```
{
  "name": "geld-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha3",
    "firebase": "^9.22.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^12.4.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've viewed any posts related to this topic, but none of the solutions worked.
Can anyone help me with this problem ?

**What I've tried**
First I had the gstatic URL's for the Firebase CLI, but now I've switched to importing from the node_modules folder, but this does not work either. I'm getting the same error message when running : npm run build
I also tried to modify the package.json file, with the following code :

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    "defaults and supports es6-module"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
}
```

but this does not work either